# Styling is not working in JQuery Data Table

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am new to JQuery datatables and I am trying to change a row color using custom styling by a condition when the table is loaded. This is working fine without any pagination.

When I implementing pagination, the custom style is working only for the current page. Eg now I am refreshing the page, the datatable stays in first page, and styling is applying for only the current page. Styling is not applying to other pages when I click other pages (like page no 2 or 3).

And also I am generating serial numbers using "fnDrawCallback", here I am also getting the same issue. I am not getting the numbers.

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

This is my data table code:

```
var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("GetReportDetails", "DailyReport")',
                "bVisible": true,
                "bDeferRender": true,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bStateSave": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                    if (oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered) {
                        for (var i = 0, iLen = oSettings.aiDisplay.length; i < iLen; i++) {
                            $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[oSettings.aiDisplay[i]].nTr).html(i + 1);
                        }
                    }
                },
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0] }
            ],
                "aoColumns": [
                        { "mData": null, align: 'Center', sWidth: '2%' },
                        { "mData": "DailyReport", align: 'left', sWidth: '18%', "bVisible": false, "mRender": function (data, type, full) { return "<div class='scrollcol' width='80%'>" + data + "</div>"; } },
                        { "mData": "CreatedOn", align: 'left', sWidth: '10%', "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                            if (full.CreatedBy != '@Session["UserId"]') {
                                if (full.ReptMgr1 == '@Session["UserId"]') {
                                    if (full.RptDisp1 == true) {
                                         $('#Dly' + full.DReportId).css('background', '#C2E0FF');
                                    }
                                } else if (full.ReptMgr2 == '@Session["UserId"]') {
                                    if (full.RptDisp2 == true) {
                                         $('#Dly' + full.DReportId).css('background', '#C2E0FF');
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        },
                        ],
                "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                    var dReptId = aData.DReportId;
                    $(nRow).attr("id", 'Dly' + dReptId);
                    $(nRow).on('click', function () {
                        var dReportId = aData.DReportId;
                        document.getElementById('reportId').value = dReportId;
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code in Firebug?

Comment: Yeah i checked it. Css is not applying for pagination

Comment: I meant have you debugged it to see WHY the css isn't applied?  I'm guessing the class isn't being set correctly.

Comment: But this same Css is working for 1st page of page load..But its not working, when i click page 2 or 3